# How to delete customer address in Address Book using netsuite php toolkit

Tags: php, web-services, netsuite

I need to delete customer address already in address book list using php tool kit.
Here is my code,

```
$service = new NetSuiteService();   


    $addressbook = new CustomerAddressBook();
    $addressbook->internalId = 'xxxxxx';  // addressBook Record (a entire row) interanl id


    $addressBookList = new CustomerAddressbookList();
    $addressBookList->addressbook = $addressbook;
    $addressBookList->replaceAll = false;

    $customer = new Customer();
    $customer->internalId =  $_SESSION["customer_internalId"]; // customer internal ID
    $customer->addressbookList = $addressBookList;

    $deleteRequest = new DeleteRequest();
    $deleteRequest->record = $customer;
    $deleteResponse = $service->delete($deleteRequest);

    print_r( $deleteResponse );
```

Whe I run this code I got exception "BaseRef is an abstract type and cannot be instantiated in ...". How to delete one of many addresses in address book list for a customer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can delete a specific subrecord within the customer record.

Look here to see the [deleted record types](https://webservices.netsuite.com/xsd/platform/v2012_1_0/coreTypes.xsd)

I would do an update request and just remove the address I don't want from the addressbooklist.  Something like this...

```
<?php
$service = new NetSuiteService();
$service->setPreferences(false, true, true, true);
$gr = new GetRequest();
$gr->baseRef = new RecordRef();
$gr->baseRef->internalId = $_SESSION["customer_internalId"]; //customer internal id
$gr->baseRef->type = "customer";
$getResponse = $service->get($gr);

if (!$getResponse->readResponse->status->isSuccess)
{
echo "GET ERROR";
}
else
{
echo "GET SUCCESS";
}

$customer = $getResponse->readResponse->record;
$arrayAddressBook = $customer->addressbookList->addressbook;

// find matching addressbook

$findAddressKey = array_filter($arrayAddressBook,
function ($e)
{
return $e->internalId == 'xxxxxx'

// addressbook internal id;

});

// grab key of that addressbook object to remove

$addressKey = key($findAddressKey);
unset($arrayAddressBook[$addressKey]);
$customer->addressbookList->replaceAll = true;
$customer->addressbookList->addressbook = $arrayAddressBook;
$request = new UpdateRequest();
$request->record = $customer;
$service->setPreferences(false, false, false, true);
$updateResponse = $service->update($request);

if (!$updateResponse->writeResponse->status->isSuccess)
{
echo "UPDATE ERROR";
}
else
{
echo "UPDATE SUCCESS, id " . $updateResponse->writeResponse->baseRef- >internalId;
}
?>
```